# Item in Meteor.Collections

Tags: meteor

Browser:

> > > Colors.insert({name: "green"});

ReferenceError: Colors is not defined [Break on this error]

```
var Colors = new Meteor.Collection("colors");
Colors.insert({name: "Red"});
var lists = new Meteor.Collection("Lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to LendLib.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
    myColor=Colors.find({}).fetch();
        console.log("You pressed the button" + myColors);
    }
  });
}
```

Where is the error?
Testing at http://kf40.ru:3000

Answer (score 0):

Meteor versions later than 0.6 encapsulate local JavaScript variables so they are only accessible from the file in which they were defined. This is why your collection is not accessible from the terminal.

Making it global should do the trick:

```
Colors = new Meteor.Collection("colors");
```